# $.post to Zapier webhook

Tags: jquery, forms, post, jekyll, zapier

I have created an HTML form that sends an HTTP POST to a Zapier webhook. The code works great when I embed the POST action in HTML:

```
<form id="contactForm" action="https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/2689457/xiooqx/" method="POST"> inputs </form>
```

However, I cannot easily ensure all fields are complete, handle responses, etc. So, I turned to JQuery:

```
    $.post('https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/2689457/xiooqx/',   // url
        { message: 'Test', contact: "NA" }, // data to be submit
        function(data, status, jqXHR) {// success callback
            alert(data);
        }
    )
```

And the same with AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/2689457/xiooqx/',           
        data: {
            message : $('#message').val(),
            contact : $('#contactMethod').val()
        },
        success:function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }          
    });
```

Neither of these work. I know the these AJAX/JQuery statements are reached, however Zapier does not receive the data.

I am using Jekyll and Gulp to render the site, so the site is static (but I still should be able to use HTTP methods). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do u get any error? add error callback to your ajax if you haven't already

Comment: Just added an error callback and no error is recorded.

Comment: i tested your ajax request i get a success response back.  {"status": "success", "attempt": "5c7077ca-590b-4b41-8125-ed135b86d940", "id": "f46ef8d6-c4db-461e-807a-7ffd12a7b23c", "request_id": "5c7077ca-590b-4b41-8125-ed135b86d940"}. It is in the Zapier endpoint you will have to investigate

Comment: I see your request went through to zapier, but it still does not for my code. Do you mind posting your code as an answer? There must be an implementation issue on my end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var data = {
            message : 'test stack overflow',
            contact : 'test'
        };
$.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/2689457/xiooqx/',  
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success:function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        // handle error
      }
    });
```

Send as JSON string

Comment: Also, in the form HTML I needed onsubmit="return false".